# What would be a good way to implement an automatic updater (a bot)

Tags: web-crawler

I'm new to this sort of thing, but I would like to create a bot that would crawl certain sites and update another one (using it for NBA statistics) every few hours or so.

I don't believe I'll have a problem coding the bot. I've dabbled in the sort of thing primarily with java (Firefox navigator plugins, Java HTTP requests, and just plain old Robot class.

What I would like to seek advice on is where and how I should maintain/run the code.

I assume I'll need to put it on a server somewhere. I could buy my own (need to eventually) or I could host it somewhere. Is there anywhere online that provides this service reliably (and perhaps at no cost)?

As for the how, what are some common setups? I'm more comfortable in Java, but I find with using any language. How do I handle the very long timespans of inactivity? Do I simply sleep the thread? Pardon my ignorance if that is a terrible solution, but I frankly have no experience in the matter. Do I need something complete like a LAMP stack or can I get by comfortably without all that? What are a  few relatively painfree ways I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For crawling a site with a bot i'd suggest using either Jsoup or Selenium 2.
I'd do the crawling on my own machine, although if you need to post that info to a server or application, you'd need a server for that one.

Generally this kind of tasks (do every x time and sleep for QUITE A WHILE) are called "cron-jobs" or just "crons".

If your crawler runs 24/7 its called a daemon.

For crons you need some sort of scheduling (how frequent you want it to run). If you are using Linux then crontab is the solution. In a text file you specify when your program runs (like every n minutes, or every day at certain time, or certain day of certain month, etc) and the OS will run your process automatically.

This way your program does it's job and closes, because the OS will start a fresh instance of your program each time.

If you don't have linux i'm sure there are windows alternatives. Otherwise there's a framework called [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) for java that can be used for that.

The only problem is that the java program will be running 24/7, except that Quartz will call your classes from time to time.